# pandas percent of group by two columns

Tags: python, pandas

i am looking for a solution to get in the result like the column "result percent of colA". as example, the value represents the percentage of cats (colB) in the month januar (colA), compared to cats and dogs in januar.

```
import pandas as pd

# set up dataframe
df_ex = pd.DataFrame({'colA':['2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-01-31', '2021-02-28', 
                              '2021-02-28', '2021-02-28', '2021-03-31', '2021-03-31'],
                   'colB':['cat', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'cat', 'dog'],
                   'colC':[1,2,3,4,4,5,6,7], })
df_ex = df_ex.groupby(['colA', 'colB']).sum() 
df_ex = df_ex.reset_index() 
df_ex['result percent of colA'] = [0.5, 0.5, 0.69, 0.31, 0.46, 0.54] #expecte result
```

thanks for help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can divide column by sum of `colC` per `colA` with same size like original with [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html):

```
df_ex['perc'] = df_ex['colC'].div(df_ex.groupby('colA')['colC'].transform('sum')).round(2)

print (df_ex)
         colA colB  colC  perc
0  2021-01-31  cat     3  0.50
1  2021-01-31  dog     3  0.50
2  2021-02-28  cat     9  0.69
3  2021-02-28  dog     4  0.31
4  2021-03-31  cat     6  0.46
5  2021-03-31  dog     7  0.54
```

**Details**:

```
print (df_ex.groupby('colA')['colC'].transform('sum'))
0     6
1     6
2    13
3    13
4    13
5    13
Name: colC, dtype: int64
```